WPF. How to wrap two ItemsControl´s using same row?
Abstracting, I have two (main) ItemsControl's that draw their content in a wrapping way.
I use WrapPanel etc.
This works well so far. Also in case the window size is changed during runtime.

But I would like to achieve is this:
Imagine first ItemsControl draws 20 items using two rows.
In terms of width, the first row is fully utilized (= "0_xxxx" ... "13_xxxx") 
while only (e.g.) 40 % of the second row is used (= "14_xxxx" ... "19_xxxx").

The second ItemsControl starts drawing its content in the (visually counted!) 3rd line.
It therefore does not use the 60% of row 2 (= "14_xxxx" ... "19_xxxx").

ItemsControl #2 should start where ItemsControl #1 has ended.

The following image shows the CURRENT, "wrong" state

https://github.com/UweR70/Images/blob/main/WPF_Test_App/2024_04_07__09_03_00.png
The complete code can be found here
https://github.com/UweR70/WPF_Test_App

I always found it best to put a grid in the row as that seems to render the best.

@WalterVerhoeven I am already using one. But may be in a wrong manner. Did you check my code?

Are you trying to have the big items start in the second line and then flow into the third line where they start from the very left again? Because then I would assume you need to have big and small items in the same WrapPanel and need a data template selector to have small and big items in the same "flow strip".

@LWChris Yes. "Small" items (= "0_xxxx" ... "19_xxxx") and "big" items ( = "0_SubLabel 0.0_yyyy ... 0.2_yyyy" ... "4_SubLabel 0.0_yyyy ... 0.2_yyyy") are already i nthe same WrapPanel - but may be I made something wrong ... . PLEASE see me yode in git hub.

To clarify your question: the image after the "And that is what I want to achieve"  sentence is the actual result and not the desired result? ItemsControl #2 should start where ItemsControl #1 has ended? Please clarify your problem.

@BionicCode You are right! Sorry! Question was not clear.
Right! The image shows the current and NOT the desired result!

Are you sure? The two templates are very different. It's going to look weird.

If I understand correctly what you want to implement, then try this implementation.
ViewModel:
using WPF_Test_App.Classes;

namespace WPF_Test_App
{
    public class OverviewComponentGroupViewModel
    {
        public OverviewComponentGroup TestData { get; }

        public OverviewComponentGroupViewModel()
        {
            TestData = new OverviewComponentGroup
            {
                Id = "Master Label",
                Components = new List<OverviewComponent> { },
                ComponentSubGroups = new List<OverviewComponentGroup> { }
            };

            // Add some dummy values
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                TestData.Components.Add(new OverviewComponent { Component = $"{i}_xxxx" });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var components = new List<OverviewComponent>();
                for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    components.Add(new OverviewComponent { Component = $"{i}.{j}_yyyy" });
                }

                TestData.ComponentSubGroups.Add(
                    new OverviewComponentGroup
                    {
                        Id = $"{i}_SubLabel",
                        Components = components
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WPF_Test_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Test_App"
        xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:WPF_Test_App.Classes"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="890"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:OverviewComponentGroupViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="items">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding TestData.Components, Source={StaticResource vm}}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding TestData.ComponentSubGroups, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
        
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:OverviewComponent}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5" Background="Brown">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Component}" Margin="5" Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:OverviewComponentGroup}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5"  Background="White">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Component}" Margin="5"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="itemsPanel">
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!-- First row for "Master Label" -->
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>    <!-- Second row for "Components" and "Component Sub Groups" -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Master label with green border -->
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestData.Id}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>

        <!-- Main "Components" and "Component Sub Groups" with red border -->
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource items}}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource itemsPanel}" />

        </Border>

    </Grid>
</Window>

using System.Windows;

namespace WPF_Test_App
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}


This works like a charm! THANK YOU! I´ve marked your answer as solution! THANK YOU!!!!

The point is that adding both ItemControl elements to a WrapPanel won't work, because the item width is the width of the ItemControl, which is the width of the full row.
The solution is to add all items to a single ItemsControl.
You can achieve this by introducing a new source collection. The disadvantage is that you would have to maintain this new collection and sync it with the original collections. . An alternative solution would be to create a custom ItemsControl (essentially, you can move the collection merge and collection change tracking around to find a suited place for the implementation).
A modified variant of the solution is to implement an IValueConverter that converts the top-level OverViewComponentGroup returned from the MainWindow.TestData property to a merged collection using the CompositeCollection class.
It's also key to bind to collections that implement INotifyCollectionChanged - in this case as the CompositeCollection needs to track changes of its underlying collections to update the binding target of the converter, but also in general to optimize memory allocations.
For this reason, your OverviewComponentGroup must initialize its collections with an e.g. ObservableCollection:
var overviewComponentGroup = new OverviewComponentGroup
{
  Id = "Some Label",
  Components = new ObservableCollection<OverviewComponent> { },
  ComponentSubGroups = new ObservableCollection<OverviewComponentGroup> { }
};

To add robustness, consider to convert the property type of the collection property definition from ICollection to ObservableCollection.
A solution to your problem could look as follows:
CollectionConcatenationConverter.cs
public class CollectionConcatenationConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (value is not OverviewComponentGroup overviewComponentGroup)
    {
      return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    var compositeCollection = new CompositeCollection
    {
      // If the source collections implement INotifyCollectionChanged, then changes are propagated to the CompositeCollection
      new CollectionContainer() { Collection = overviewComponentGroup.Components },
      new CollectionContainer() { Collection = overviewComponentGroup.ComponentSubGroups }
    };

    return compositeCollection;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:CollectionConcatenationConverter x:Key="CollectionConcatenationConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <!-- First row for "Master Label" -->
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <!-- Second row for components and subgroup components -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Master label with green border -->
    <Border BorderBrush="Green"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Margin="5"
            Grid.Row="0">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestData.Id}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>

    <!-- Main Components and Subgroup Components with red border -->
    <Border BorderBrush="Red"
            BorderThickness="3"
            Margin="5"
            Grid.Row="1">

      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TestData, Converter={StaticResource CollectionConcatenationConverter}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
          <Binding Path="TestData">
            <Binding.Converter>

              <!-- Because the converter has a state, we have to use an instance per Binding -->
              <local:CollectionConcatenationConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
          </Binding>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>

        <ItemsControl.Resources>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:OverviewComponent}">

            <!-- Set VerticalAlignment="Top". Otherwise the smaller items appear as large as the bigger ones -->
            <Border VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    BorderBrush="Gray"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Margin="5">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Component}"
                         Margin="5" />
            </Border>
          </DataTemplate>

          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type classes:OverviewComponentGroup}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Margin="5">
              <StackPanel>
                <Border VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        BorderBrush="Green"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        Margin="5"
                        Grid.Row="0">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <WrapPanel>
                  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Margin="5">
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Component}"
                                     Margin="5" />
                        </Border>
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel />
                      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                  </ItemsControl>
                </WrapPanel>
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</Window>


@BioniCode WOW. Thank you very much for your effort. But unfortunately I can't get it to work. I create a new class "CollectionConcatenationConverter.cs" but can not reference it in the xaml?! Seems I am too tired. I´ve changed my code in git hub. May I a sk you to guide me please again? THANKS!

Maybe a rebuild will fix it. It looks like you found a solution.
